# Excel gannt chart one event with multiple duration

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, events

I'm working on a large dataset which I need to plot a timeline in gantt chart fashion (horizontal bars with y-axis the event/task and x-axis time) but one event/task has multiple duration for instance how would you plot this gantt chart:

Event A: taking place between Monday to Tuesdays AND Saturday to Sunday

Event B: taking place Tuesday to Wednesday

Event C: taking place Wednesday to Thursday

I was following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/xsxi4qaEnOg), but since task A has 2 durations the gantt chart will have 4 tasks in the y axis as task A will be repeated: one bar with only monday to tuesday and another bar with saturday to sunday.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a fixed maximum number of separate durations a single task can have? If it's a very low number, it might be feasible to adapt Jon Peltier's method which is essentially data prep then a simple stacked bar chart with some invisible series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is somewhat tedious, it can be easily achieved. First, you need to prepare your data to have a numeric event number, numeric start day or date, and duration. The data used looks like this:

[image: data]

Select columns B, C, F and insert a Stacked Bar chart that looks as follows:

[image: bar chart]

Select the vertical axis -> right-click -> Format Axis... -> Change Axis Type to Date Axis. In this step, all the same event numbers are combined in one row.

Next, you need to deal with the problem that your events are text data. To do this, create an auxiliary matrix that contains the unique event names and an axis column:

[image: helper data]

Copy this matrix -> Select Chart -> Add the matrix to the chart as a new series via Paste Special. In this step, you need to select the Series Names in First Row and the Categories (X Labels) in First Column. Now you need to make sure that the column is connected to the secondary axis. You can do this by selecting the chart -> Chart Design -> Change Chart Type -> Combo. All charts have the Stacked Bar type and the new auxiliary matrix is on the secondary axis. Add the secondary axis by selecting the chart -> Chart Design -> Add Chart Element -> Axes -> Secondary Vertical. You can also reverse the values in both axes so that they run from 1-3 (A-C), but that depends on your needs. Delete the horizontal axis connected to the secondary axis and keep only the date axis. Change the label position of the textual y-axis to low via Format Axis... -> Labels -> Label position and delete the y-axis with values.

Finally, you can change the color of your data series to suit your needs. In particular, you want to change the color of the blue bars (no duration) to no fill.

The final chart looks as follows:

[image]